# How to increase size of Ubuntu azure VM scale set

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

So my client has created a Virtual machine Scale Set in Azure which has a OS disk of Linux of 30 GB for Ubuntu.

How can I increase it to say 1024 GB without loosing any data

Orchestration is
uniform

In properties it said

Empherical disk
N/A

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expand the size of OS disks in azure scale sets directly via Portal.
You can use custom images for your base image in scale sets and the set the size of your custom image to your requirement and then accordingly use that image in vmss. Here is how you can do that : [Use custom VM image in VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-cli#create-a-scale-set-from-the-image)

Or, you can go ahead and attach data disks of the required size to your scale set if that can fit your requirement..
Here is the link to that : [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-disks-cli)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).